# TypeScript issue with importing declarations

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue with importing declarations from an extended file (I am using [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/3fc1377ce29dd9670975cb68615edf1b819fc4a5/sockjs-client) typing). According to [example](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3fc1377ce29dd9670975cb68615edf1b819fc4a5/sockjs-client/sockjs-client-tests.ts), I should put this into my code:

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import BaseEvent = __SockJSClient.BaseEvent;
import SockJSClass = __SockJSClient.SockJSClass;
```

However, when I try to do this as following:

```
module Test {
    import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
    import BaseEvent = __SockJSClient.BaseEvent;
    import SockJSClass = __SockJSClient.SockJSClass;

    export class Example {
        constructor() {......
}}}
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

```
error TS1147: Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any issue with the typing itself?

Thanks
uksz

Comment: did you reference the `d.ts` file as `/// <reference path="./sockjs-client.d.ts" />` or in common `tsd.d.ts` and keep the import out of the module

Answer (score 13):

You should use your import statements outside your module

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import BaseEvent = __SockJSClient.BaseEvent;
import SockJSClass = __SockJSClient.SockJSClass;

module Test {
    export class Example {
        constructor(){}
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as I put it outside my namespace, everything else starts to break.  I guess it's causing my code to be registered as an external module and then it can no longer see other third-party libraries.  Is there something I can do to fix that?  Thanks

Comment: @AdamPlocher I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @romanoza I stopped using `module` or `namespace`. I was racking my brain trying to remember why, but I came across an answer I wrote to another question (just 2 days after this comment, which I apparently forgot about). It seems to address this topic exactly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43023392/730566

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to a mix of the typescript module options.

Your class uses internal modules and the typing file uses external modules.
See the Working with other JavaScript libraries section here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded to use imported typings in my customizing Cypress code using the same syntax as them :

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
```

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/3e8b52f3deb82b5d29b959cbbe01917010fa5f92/packages/net-stubbing/lib/external-types.ts#L368

So it works at least in a namespace, not tested in a ts module but I hope it does too.

It seems to only work in this certain context because if I comment out my `import`s it throws: `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)`. But if you are there, that's you want to import/export something.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when trying to import `moment.d.ts` type definition file in one of my typescript file.

I'm also wrapping my whole class inside a `module`.  The solution that I did to solve the issue was, in my typescript file - `Scheduler.ts`, I put the line `import * as moment from "../definitions/moment/moment";` just before the `module` declaration (refer to image below).

I didn't include the whole class definition for brevity reason.

[image]

As you can see, I have `reference path` explicitly define in the typescript file for external libraries (`jquery`, `kendo ui` and `moment`).

The folder structure where type definitions are saved.

[image]

Below is also my `tsconfig.json`, not quite sure setting this  `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true` ease the problem.  I just followed the notes written on this [link](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/00-use-it/08-typescript/) when importing and using in typescript file.

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```