# TypeScript 2.0: How can I reference objects in the same namespace but in a sub folder?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Using TypeScript 2 namespaces, how do I get code to recognize classes added to a namespace in a sub folder.

(I am using AngularJS 1.5 and Webpack, but neither of these *should* play a part in this.)

In the below example, directive D1 is in a folder under directives, and _bootstrap_directives.ts can not resolve it.  It gets this error:

**error TS2339: Property 'D1Directive' does not exist on type 'typeof Directives'.**

Perhaps I just need to create myLibrary.d.ts to explicitly define the contract?

-

```
directives
> d1
  > d1.directive.ts
  > d1.scss
> _bootstrap_directives.ts
> d2.directive.ts
```

-

```
> d1.directive.ts (d2.directive is the same with a different class name and no scss import)

import './d1.scss'; // for webpack
namespace MyLibrary.Directives {
    export class D1Directive implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict: string = 'A';
        scope: boolean = false;

        constructor() {
            // noop
        }
        static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            const directive = () => {
                return new D1Directive();
            }
            return directive;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
> _bootstrap_directives.ts (

// Property 'D1Directive' does not exist on type 'typeof Directives'. 
import './d1/d1.directive';  // for webpack
angular.module('myLibrary')
    .directive('d1', MyLibrary.Directives.D1Directive.factory()); 

// This one works
import './d2.directive'; // for webpack
angular.module('myLibrary')
    .directive('d2', MyLibrary.Directives.D2Directive.factory());
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out webpack WAS the issue.  Leaving this here to help the community.

Moving this line from d1.directive.ts to the bootstrap file removed the issue.

```
import './d1.scss';
```

So lesson learned - don't import in a subfolder outside of a namespace.

Comment: The general lesson is to avoid namespaces (internal modules). Namespaces is a concept that was introduced before it was clear that JavaScript would move to a proper module system with ES6. Nowadays, you should [just use modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) (i.e. “external modules” in TypeScript)

Comment: I actually did switch to using modules instead of namespaces.  Unfortunately, the exact same issue occurs.  An import statement above module Library.Blah.Blah causes the TS compiler to not find the exported class. Even if that .ts file is in the same folder.

Comment: I wouldn't say webpack is the issue.  I would say that the import at the top is the issue (TypeScript).  I realize this post is a bit old, but I've been fighting with this for the last week.  See my answer for a little more info.

Comment: @poke why do you say that?  Where on that link you sent does it say not to use namespaces?  That link seems to say the opposite

Comment: @AdamPlocher The documentation doesn’t mention it because it’s still a supported thing (and for some things the only way to do something). The general advice is to use (external) modules since they follow what the ES6 standard does. See also: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827281/modules-vs-namespaces-what-is-the-correct-way-to-organize-a-large-typescript-p

Answer (score 4):

I've been fighting with this issue for days, and even though I seem to have a grasp on it now, it's still driving me nuts.

For my local/internal development within my project, I stopped using modules (or namespaces), which should make it always run on the global scope (not the greatest but it works for now I guess).

The reason your import is breaking things is..

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
>   top-level import or export is considered a module.

So why does being a module make all your references disappear? ...

> Modules are executed within their own scope, not in the global scope;
>   this means that variables, functions, classes, etc. declared in a
>   module are not visible outside the module unless they are explicitly
>   exported using one of the export forms. Conversely, to consume a
>   variable, function, class, interface, etc. exported from a different
>   module, it has to be imported using one of the import forms.

[See here for more info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).